# VBA form is not retaining data if a new form is closed with "X"

Tags: forms, vba

I've created a form in which a user can double click on a list box entry to open another form for info. When the user closes the new form I want the existing data on the original form to remain. In my current code, however, the original data is not retained if the user clicks "X" to close the new form.

Code:

```
Private Sub lstServiceHistory_DblClick (ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   frmJobDetails.Show
End Sub
```

How can I get the data to remain on the original form?

Comment: You will need to show the rest of the code - this doesn't really tell us anything.

Comment: Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

          InitialiseForm

     End Sub

Comment: On the main form I have a 'Reg' field, which user the Afterupdate event to pull in all the other vehicle details and populate a User defined class. The Reg field seems to be set to "" and then the screen updates when I return to the original form after closing the display form.

Comment: Private Sub cboVehicleReg_afterupdate()
             CheckRegExists
     End Sub

Comment: These bits of code just call other subs - it still doesn't tell us what's happening. Can you edit your question and post all the code that affects this userform?

Comment: Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
     'Fill all combo boxes and lists from DB
            InitialiseForm
     End Sub
     Private Sub cboVehicleReg_afterupdate()
            CheckRegExists
     End Sub
    Private Sub cboVehicleReg_click()
          CheckRegExists 'Sub to check entered reg against db
     end sub                                                                                                Private Sub lstServiceHistory_DblClick()
    frmJobDetails.Show 
End Sub
   Private Sub InitialiseForm()
        cboVehicleReg.SetFocus
   end sub

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the code there in the appropriate formatting - not in a comment.

Comment: Basically my form runs userform_activate() again when I close the other form and I don't want this to happen. Any ideas.

Comment: Create a public boolean variable that gets set to true, use an if statement to exit the sub if that variable is true

Comment: or use the `UserForm_Initialize()` event instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a boolean check in the form_Activate event to see if the form had already been initialised.